# How do I use a standard object as a parameter for a lightning component? Specifically a helper class to create a case

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components

I'm using the Lightning Component Developer guide and stuck at a final step. In the guide, they are using an Expense__c object. In my case I'm trying to use Case. In the final step, they use helper classes to add an expense.

Here is the code they use:

```
createExpense: function(component, expense) {
this.upsertExpense(component, expense, function(a) {
    var expenses = component.get("v.expenses");
    expenses.push(a.getReturnValue());
    component.set("v.expenses", expenses);
    this.updateTotal(component);
  });
},

upsertExpense : function(component, expense, callback) {
    var action = component.get("c.saveExpense");
    action.setParams({ 
        "expense": expense
    });
    if (callback) {
      action.setCallback(this, callback);
    }
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

In the function definition, they use expense and here I want to use case. Except when I do update it, I get an error. Here is my code:

```
createCase: function(component, case) {
    this.upsertCase(component, case, function(a) {
        var cases = component.get("v.cases");
        cases.push(a.getReturnValue());
        component.set("v.cases", cases);
      });
},

upsertCase : function(component, case, callback) {
    var action = component.get("c.saveCase");
    action.setParams({ 
        "case": case
    });
    if (callback) {
      action.setCallback(this, callback);
    }
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

This is the error I get:

Something has gone wrong. Error during init [TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined]
.
Please try again.

Comment: Did you write Apex controller with saveCase auraEnabled method?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the type of the object in 2 places:

In the client side in the component's markup:

```
<aura:attribute name="case" type="Case" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case' , 'OwnerId': 'your id' }"/>
```

And in your server side AuraEnabled apex controller. Then you return the case you have created to your component's javascript controller.